# Install and Configure XHProf (Ubuntu)

Tags: 7, debugging

**Problem**

I'm trying to use XHProf but I'm getting horrible php error every time it runs.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xhprof_compute_inclusive_times() (line 1670 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/XHProf/xhprof.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in xhprof_compute_flat_info() (line 1644 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/XHProf/xhprof.inc).
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in theme_xhprof_overall_summary() (line 367 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/XHProf/xhprof.module).
```

The problem is solved [here](https://drupal.org/node/1377792) because the temporary folder doesn't exist, however mine does.

**Set-Up Server Side**

I'm running a fresh Ubuntu Server 13.04 with Drupal 7.

Install xhprof using `pear` following the instructions [here](http://queirozf.com/reminders/installing-xhprof-php-profiler-on-ubuntu).
I also added a temporary directory to php.ini, which I created manually.

```
extension=xhprof.so
xhprof.output_dir="/var/tmp/xhprof"
```

**Drupal Set-Up**

I have both the devel installed and I also installed the XHProf module.

In `admin/config/development/xhprof`, I enabled profiling of all page views and drush requests.

On following an xhprof link I get the error above.

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Good god Batman. That was incredibly frustrating. Here's a guide to getting xhprof working. (Note: I am very new to Linux. I'm not sure if the permissions I use are safe, or whether there is a better way of doing it. I'd only do this on a test environment.)

IMPORTANT: It won't tell you anything about how to interpret it. I have no idea how to, I'm just happy it works.

**Getting XHProf Working**

**1. What operating system are you running?**

Mac or Linux?

It's possible.

Windows?

Probably not. To run xhprof on windows you have to have a compiled dll. There's a link to one in this [thread](https://drupal.org/node/1011108), but I always had compatibility issues with it when I tried to use it on XAMPP.

I think it was compiled with a different version of Apache.

**2. Getting it working on Ubuntu**

It's possible on Mac. Here are two useful links:

http://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/installing-xhprof-mamp-and-php-52-mac-os-106-snow-leopard
http://www.midwesternmac.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/getting-xhprof-working-well

But I haven't done it. I managed to get it working on Ubuntu Server 13.04, although I think any recent version of Ubuntu Server would work.

I set-up my server on VirtualBox. [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is free but it might take a bit to learn how to set it up.

**3.Installing XHProf**

I'm going to assume we have a fully functioning Ubuntu Server.

First we need to install pear. We'll use this to install XHProf.

```
sudo apt-get install pear
```

We follow this up with phpdev which is also needed.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev
```

If these commands don't work and I've got them wrong, just go straight ahead with:

```
sudo pecl install -f xhprof
```

Ubuntu will tell you what you're missing and give you the prompt to install it. Once you've got all the dependencies install xhprof.

You might get an error on installing xhprof, it'll try to download the beta and fail. In that case try:

```
sudo pecl install -f xhprof-beta
```

Hopefully xhprof is now installed.

Now we need to configure it. Open your php.ini which is at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
and add the following two lines under the extensions section:

```
extension=xhprof.so
xhprof.output_dir="/var/tmp/xhprof"
```

The second line sets the output directory. If this folder doesn't exist you'll have to create it.When you've done that reboot apache using

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**4. Checking if XHProf is running**

Now we need to check if that worked.

Test 1:

Enter `php -m`

If you see xhprof in the list you're good to go. If not, don't worry, try this instead to check if it's working:

Go to your webroot `/var/www/` and create a php file with only:

```
phpinfo();
```

Save it as phpinfo.php. Open this in your browser and you should see PHP information. Search for xhprof and if you see this then it's running.

[image]

**5. Getting it working with Drupal**

I couldn't get it working with the Drupal module. So instead I'm going to tell you how to get it working with the devel module.

First some config that I borrowed from [here](http://www.pixelite.co.nz/article/profiling-drupal-7-performance-xhprof-and-devel). I didn't really follow this part, but it works so gift horse and all that.

Create a new config file with the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/xhprof.conf
```

and insert the following code.

```
alias /xhprof_html "/usr/share/php/xhprof_html/"
```

Then we possibly need to create a symlink to our xhprof_html folder. So just in case set this:

ln -s /usr/share/php/xhprof_html /var/www/xhprof_html

This will create a folder in your webroot that points to the existing xhprof file. Then in your browser you can open http://mywebsitehere.com/xhprof to see all the runs you've made.

Then restart apache. Now it's time for a little devel config. Go to the devel settings, enable xhprof and set:

```
xhprof directory = /usr/share/php

XHProf URL = /xhprof_html
```

Now at the bottom of each page you should see a little link to xhprof.

[image]

And clicking it should take you to a page that looks like this. You're done. Congratulations!

[image]

If that didn't work and you're getting run errors it's probably because Drupal doesn't have permission to write to the tmp folder that we set earlier so enter:

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/tmp/xhprof
```

And hopefully that works. We're done. Hoorah!

Unless you want graphing functions. Thankfully that's as easy as:

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And now you should have graphing functions. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Wow, impressive answer. For what it's worth, the permissions you've used seem sane.

Comment: Yeah there was some serious pain getting that to work. Hopefully it'll help someone else (and me in two months when I've forgotten).

Comment: Great answer, works perfectly, thanx to relieve the pain :-)

Comment: I don't have `/etc/apache2/conf.d` directory. I made   `sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/xhprof.conf` and `a2enconf xhprof` instead

Comment: Thanks for the run-through.  On Ubuntu 14.04 I installed from the Ubuntu repositories rather than PEAR, and found I needed to execute `php5enmod xhprof` in order to create the priority symlink from the conf.d directory to the mods-available directory xhprof.ini file.  Another way to check if xhprof is enabled is to run `php5-fpm -i | grep xhprof`, replacing php5-fpm with whatever SAPI you're checking.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the symlink command is misprinted in Dominic Woodman's answer. ls -s /usr/share/php/xhprof_html /var/www/xhprof should be: ln -s /usr/share/php/xhprof_html /var/www/xhprof_html i.e. replace "ls" with "ln" and "/var/www/xhprof" with "/var/www/xhprof_html" to be consistent with suggested Devel settings path.

Comment: adding entry in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and checking with `php -m` won't work on Ubuntu as you are checking with `cli` and have not made entry in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` - best to make both

Comment: Impressive answer (and interesting question)! There are people on Drupal.SE who don't like loooooooong / detailed answers, but "I" do like them ... PS: welcome also to the land of +1K ...

Comment: For which version of PHP did you install it? I have PHP 5.4 but it complains that the module was compiled for the earlier version. Any idea how to fix this?  
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: xhprof: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
`